# Buildbot slave environment path

Tags: buildbot

I wanted to know where buildbot is retrieving the PATH environment from?

My problem is the following:
I am compiling on MACOSX with zsh.
My master.cfg is well configured to use zsh since in the stdio I get :
SHELL=/bin/zsh

But my path is not the path configured in .zsh.

For now I hotfixed that by adding env={"PATH"=["PathIWant"]} but I find it a bit hacky and does not really like that solution.
I would prefer the buildbot slave to get the right path from the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention `master.cfg`, keep in mind that the commands execute on the slave, not the master -- so the PATH on the master doesn't matter.

The environment on the slave is simply the environment in which the slave was started.  For example,

`export PATH=/path/i/want:$PATH
buildslave start /path/to/slave`

would put `/path/i/want` in PATH for any commands executed by that slave instance.